# Twitter bot to auto reply to specified hashtags

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I need help regarding a twitter bot which I am trying to make (which will reply to a particular phrase or hashtag) but something is wrong. I will appreciate if anyone can help solve it.

```
var Twit = require ('twit');

var config = require('./config');
var T = new Twit(config);

   for (var i = 0; i < tweetList.length; i++) {
    var id = { id: tweetList[i].id_str }
    if ('retweeted_status' in tweetList[i]) 
        continue;
    }
    var message = "A lot confused, a lot does not understand feelings";
    var tweetId = tweetList[i].id_str

    try {
        T.post('statuses/update',
            { "status": message, "in_reply_to_status_id": tweetId },
            function (error, tweets, response) {
                console.log("Tweet posted successfully!")
            });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }  
});
```

it gives an error like cannot read id_str and before that, it was giving an error like screen name is not defined

Comment: this code will be there  after var T = new Twit(config);  it was not allowing me to post this question was giving error so i am writing the initial portion in the comment here    var query = "alot";
T.get('search/tweets',
    { q: query, count: 1, lang: "en" },
    function (_error, tweets) {
        var tweetList = tweets['statuses'];

Comment: can you share the value of tweetList?

Comment: That is the complete code which I have if there is any extra things needs to be added pls help me with that.  may be this is  what you are asking  var tweetList = tweets['statuses]

Comment: here is the github link for full code: https://github.com/jagdeepjd11/twitter-reply-bot/blob/master/README.md

Comment: i meant console log the value of tweetList and share that value

Comment: it gives this error even when doing console log var tweetId = tweetList[i].id_str     TypeError: Cannot read property 'id_str' of undefined
    at D:\node\test.js:22:40
    at D:\node\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:127:13
    at onRequestComplete (D:\node\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:352:5)

Comment: pls bear with me as i am complete noob. appreciate your patience

Comment: You are missing this line T.get('search/tweets', { q: query, count: 1, lang: "en" }, function (_error, tweets) { var tweetList = tweets['statuses'];}

Comment: ok but now when I run it it says bot is starting but then nothing happens.  D:\node>node test.js
the bot is starting

D:\node>